# select-options crush low and high values

Tags: abap, select-options

Below code

```
s_pruef-sign = 'I'.
s_pruef-options = 'BT'.
s_pruef-low = ''.
s_pruef-high = ''.
APPEND s_pruef.
```

produced this:

[image]

How can I remove these default 0 values from select-options ?

I tried `CLEAR s_pruef` commmand but didn't work.

Comment: Please indicate full code for reproducing (`select-options` for `Kontrol partisi`)

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
REFRESH s_pruef[].
```

or

```
FREE s_pruef[].
```

Answer (score 1):

On the selection screen:
Click here:
[image]

A popup comes up, click here and the select option will be initial (press F8 after that to return to the selection screen):

[image]

In the program: Instead of *CLEAR s_pruef* you have to use:

```
CLEAR s_pruef[].
```

Select options are internal tables with header lines, s_pruef refers to the header line, s_pruef[] refers to the internal table.